# Should I choose "increasingly" or "increasing"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> An **increasingly/increasing** large number of people are using online travel sites rather than travel agents.

**Increasingly** is a adverb , **increasing** is adjective.

So Which should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

> Increasingly is a adverb , increasing is adjective.

Adverbs modify verbs or other modifiers.

Adjectives modify nouns.

So you have to figure out what *increasing[ly]* is modifying.

> An increasingly/increasing large number of people are using online travel sites rather than travel agents.

*Large* is a modifier that is modifying *people* - and we are saying that it's getting larger and larger over time.  The largeness is increasing.

So *increasingly* - the adverb is used.

Answer (score -1):

Since the word
increasing is modifying the words "large number", which is a noun, the correct word is increasing.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners Stack Exchange and thank your for your contribution. Unfortunately, that is not the correct answer ...

Answer (score -2):

EITHER

An increasingly large number of people...

OR

An increasing number of people....

The second is more economical, but some people might think that the longer form adds emphasis.